# How to transpose a matrix in C? - error

Tags: c, matrix, transpose

I am trying to write a function to transpose matrices.

paramters of that function:

- the matrix to transpose
- the output matrix which is empty.

The problem is I am able to transpose some matrices but some other fail like the one i am giving in my example. WHy? how could I solve it?

code:

```
int main (void)
{

//this works well
/*  double array[3][2] = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
    height = 3;
    width = 2;
*/
//this input doesn't work

    double array[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    height = 2;
    width = 3;


int heightOutput =  width; //2
int widthOutput = height; //3

    double **output;

    output = malloc(widthOutput * sizeof(double *)); //rows from 1
    for (i = 0; i < widthOutput; i++)
    {
        output[i] = malloc(heightOutput * sizeof(double)); //columns
    }

    transposeMatrix(&array[0][0], height,width, &output[0][0], heightOutput, widthOutput);

            printf("\n");
            printf("\noutput matrix\n");
    for(i=0;i<heightOutput;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<widthOutput;j++)
        {
            printf("%f\t",output[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}



void transposeMatrix(double* array2, int height, int width, double * output, int height2, int width2)
{


    double workaround[3][3] ={0};
    double result;
    int i,j;

printf("input matrix:\n");


for(i=0;i<height;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<width;j++)
        {
                printf("%f\t",(*((array2+i*width)+j)));

        }
        printf("\n");
    }


        printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<width2;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<height2;j++)
        {
            result = (*((array2+i*width)+j));
            workaround[i][j] = result;
        }
    }


    for(i=0;i<width2;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<height2;j++)
        {
            *((output+j*3)+i) = workaround[i][j];
            printf("%f\t",(*((output+j*3)+i)));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


}
```

Comment: When asking others to read your code, please use spaces. Like this: `result = (*((array2 + i * width) + j));` Makes it easier for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you confused with sizes of matrices.

1. When you fill `workaround` matrix your loop should be like this, since size of original matrix is (`height` x `width`).

   ```
   for(i=0;i<width;i++)
   {
       for(j=0;j<height;j++)
       {
           result = (*((array2+i*width)+j));
           workaround[i][j] = result;
       }
   }
   ```
2. When transposing matrix

   ```
   for(i=0;i<height2;i++)
   {
       for(j=0;j<width2;j++)
       {
          *((output+i*width2)+j) = workaround[j][i];
          printf("%f\t",(*((output+i*width2)+j)));
       }
   }
   ```
3. In memory allocation you also got wrong sizes, it should be

   ```
   output = malloc(heightOutput * sizeof(double *)); //rows from 1
   for (i = 0; i < heightOutput; i++)
   {
       output[i] = malloc(widthOutput * sizeof(double)); //columns
   }
   ```

   With this changes your program will run without errors, but output is still wil be wrong

   ```
   input matrix:                                                                                                                                                                    
   1.000000        2.000000        3.000000                                                                                                                                         
   4.000000        5.000000        6.000000                                                                                                                                         

   1.000000        2.000000        3.000000                                                                                                                                         
   4.000000        5.000000        6.000000                                                                                                                                         


   output matrix                                                                                                                                                                    
   1.000000        4.000000                                                                                                                                                         
   5.000000        0.000000                                                                                                                                                         
   0.000000        0.000000
   ```
4. The last problem is with argument passing. You dynamically allocate memory, pointers to rows first

   ```
   output = malloc(heightOutput * sizeof(double *)); //rows from 1
   ```

   With this you got array of pointers

   ```
   * -> NULL
   * -> NULL
   * -> NULL
   ```

   and with loop you assign values to them

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < heightOutput; i++)
   {
       output[i] = malloc(widthOutput * sizeof(double)); //columns
   }

   * -> [e00, e01]
   * -> [e10, e11]
   * -> [e20, e21]
   ```

   But there is no guarantee that they will be allocated one after another, still you operate with `output` like with linear allocated data. To correctly work with this you need to pass double pointer.

   ```
   void transposeMatrix(double* array2, int height, int width, double ** output, int height2, int width2)
   {
       ...
       for(i=0;i<width2;i++)
       {
           for(j=0;j<height2;j++)
           {
               output[j][i] = workaround[i][j];
               printf("%f\t",output[j][i]);
           }
           printf("\n");
       }
   }
   ```

   If you want to allocate memory linear do it like follows

   ```
   output = malloc(heightOutput * widthOutput * sizeof(double));
   ```

But to me all of it looks kind of complicated, simply it would looks like

```
void transposeMatrix(double* src, double* dst, int n, int m)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        for(j = 0; j < m; ++j)
            dst[j * n + i] = src[i * m + j];
}

int main(void)
{
    double array[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    int height = 2;
    int width = 3;
    int i, j;

    double *output = malloc(height * width * sizeof(double));

    printf("input matrix\n");
    for(i=0;i<height;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<width;j++)
        {
            printf("%f\t",array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    transposeMatrix(&array[0][0], output, height,width);

    printf("output matrix\n");
    for(i=0;i<width;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<height;j++)
        {
            printf("%f\t",output[i*height + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
To answer to your comment: Let' say we have matrix 4 * 5

```
| a00 a01 a02 a03 a04 |
| a10 a11 a12 a13 a14 |
| a20 a21 a22 a23 a24 |
| a30 a31 a32 a33 a34 |
```

In memory allocated with

```
// n = 4, m = 5
double* A = malloc(n * m * sizeof(double));
```

it will look like

```
| a00 a01 a02 a03 a04 a10 a11 a12 a13 a14 a20 a21 a22 a23 a24 a30 a31 a32 a33 a34 |
```

So to get element let's say (2, 3) we need to skip 2 * 5 elements (it's two rows each of 5 elements) and 3 elements from the beginning of the third row, so - 13 elements to skip in array.
And to generalize for matrix m * n to get (i, j) element we need to skip (i * m) + j elements in array.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much, this worked.
Would it be possible to get some information about what this notation means/does output[i*height + j]

Comment: @trilolil It's the same as ``*((output+i*height)+j))``. When you allocate memory for matrix lineary as ``double* A = malloc(n*m*sizeof(double))`` you can access (i, j) element with ``A[i*m+j]``.

Comment: But what I don't understand is why you need this multiplication?

Answer (score 0):

```
include stdio.h  
include conio.h 
include string.h
include stdlib.h

int main(){

    int i,j,n,t=0,a[100][100],k,l,b=0;

    printf(" n="); // you write the number or rows and columns or the matrix
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){ //you write the elements of the matrix
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++){
            printf("a[%d][%d]=",i,j);
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){ //you can see you original matrix
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++){
            printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
        } 
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n -\n");

    for (i=2; i<=n; i++) { //now we transpose the original matrix
        for (j=1; j < i; j++) {
            t = a[i][j];
            a[i][j] = a[j][i];
            a[j][i] = t;
            printf("\n da \n");
         }
   }
```

// now we can see the transpose of the matrix

// and compare it to the first one

```
printf("\n  \n ");

for(i=1;i<=n;i++){ 
    for(j=1;j<=n;j++){
        printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
printf("\n  \n");

system("PAUSE");

return 0;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's helpful to explain your solution in English as well as providing a code sample.

Comment: Welcome to SO and to expand upon @MattRaines's comment, please double check your code's formatting.

Comment: Thank you for your warm welcoming :)